# phpMyAdmin randomly shows blank content pages?

Tags: ubuntu, php, phpmyadmin, iframe

When using phpMyAdmin in firefox and Chrome in Ubuntu 9.10 the main content area iframe often fails to load - leaving me with a blank white content area (though the sidebar is still there).

Firebug reports that the iframe or AJAX response makes it back - but it fails to load in the  iframe area. It seems to be tied to the SQL queries I try to run as just clicking normal links like table names works.

My guess is that both browsers may be choking on a bad response from phpMyAdmin - or maybe the sessions it uses are messing up causing die()'s or something on the PHP side. I think I remember something about Ubuntu's /tmp being locked down...

Here's a copy of the response I get in firebug.

```
Response    Headers view source
Date        Tue, 02 Mar 2010 05:13:36 GMT
Server      Apache/2.2.12 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.2.10-2ubuntu6.4
Set-Cookie  pma_fontsize=deleted; expires=Mon, 02-Mar-2009 05:13:35 GMT; path=/phpmyadmin/ pma_fontsize=deleted; expires=Mon, 02-Mar-2009 05:13:35 GMT; path=/phpmyadmin/ pma_theme=deleted; expires=Mon, 02-Mar-2009 05:13:35 GMT; path=/phpmyadmin/
Expires Tue, 02 Mar 2010 05:13:46 GMT
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0
Last-Modified   Tue, 02 Mar 2010 05:13:46 GMT
X-ob_mode   1
Pragma      no-cache
Vary        Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  20
Keep-Alive  timeout=15, max=90
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
```

**Update:** it only happens when POST requests are sent such as SQL queries or the pop-up window query box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I increased the memory limit to 16MB and execution time to 20sec in the php.ini file and now I'm not having any trouble with phpmyadmin. Strange, I thought that going over those limits would at least show an error or something.